# Compute the number of light- and dark- periods between two dates in Python

Tags: python, datetime

This is a calculation I encountered in a program of mine recently:

> given 2 dates and a light/dark cycle, calculate the (fractional) number of light and dark periods occurring between those dates.

```
def foo(start_date, end_date, lights_on, lights_off):
    #stuff...
    return (daytimes, nighttimes)
```

- `start_date` and `end_date` are datetime objects with (at least) minute precision
- `lights_on` and `lights_off` are `int` and represent the hour of the day when lights turn on and off (respectively).  These are what define the duration of the "lights on" and "lights off" periods.
- `lights_on` and `lights_off` **can unequally divide the day** (i.e. it doesn't have to be 12H light:12H dark), and the **light cycle doesn't have to match "true" day and nighttime** (e.g. the lights can be turn off at 7am and turn on at 7pm).  However, it is assumed that the **light cycle will be constant** (i.e. imagine lights in a room or building, not sunrise/sunset) and the **lights will always turn on or off at the turn of the hour** (e.g. the lights can't change at 8:30pm).
- The results should be `float` representations of the *number* of completed lights-on periods and  lights-off periods between the 2 dates.
- You can assume the dates are less than a month apart, during a period when DST isn't changing.

Examples:

```
import pandas as pd

date1 = pd.Timestamp(year=2020, month=1, day=1, hour=9, minute=0)
date2 = pd.Timestamp(year=2020, month=1, day=3, hour=13, minute=0)
date3 = pd.Timestamp(year=2020, month=1, day=5, hour=20, minute=47)

foo(date1, date2, 9, 17)
#returns (2.5, 2)

foo(date1, date3, 9, 17)
#returns (5, 4.236...)

foo(date1, date2, 19, 7)
#returns (2, 2.333...)
```

Explanations:

- With a light cycle of 9:00 to 17:00, there are *2.5 completed light periods* (9:00 to 17:00 on Jan 1st, 9:00 to 17:00 on Jan 2nd, and 9:00 to 13:00 on Jan 3rd) and *2 completed dark periods* (all of the night of Jan 1st and all of the night of Jan second) between `date1` and `date2`.
- With a light cycle of 9:00 to 17:00, there are *5 completed light periods* (9:00 to 17:00 on Jan 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, and 5th) and *4.236.. completed dark periods* (all of the night of Jan 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and 4th, then an additional 3 hours and 47 minutes of darkness from 17:00 until 20:47, which is 0.236... times the length of one dark cycle) between `date1` and `date3`.
- With a **light cycle** of **19:00 to 7:00**, there are *2 completed light periods* (19:00 to 7:00 on the night of Jan 1st and 2nd) and *2.333.. completed dark periods* (10/12 of a dark cycle on Jan 1st from 9:00 to 17:00 + 12/12 of a dark cycle from 7:00 to 17:00 on Jan 2nd + 6/12 of a dark cycle on Jan 3rd from 7:00 to 13:00 = 28/12 = 2.333....) between `date1` and `date2`.

To me, this computation was easy to conceptualize but difficult to code.  I have an answer (posted below) which works, but I struggled with it for a long time and would like to see different and better approaches.  If there are existing libraries which can be used that is great, and I don't care if the data are represented differently as long as the output is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternate solution that attempts to simplify the maths by offsetting the start and end times by the minimum of `lights_on` and `lights_off` so that the cycles for each day effectively consist of one change at `abs(lights_on - lights_off)`. I've done all the maths using `datetime.timedelta` objects.

```
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta

def cycle_times(start_date, end_date, lights_on):
    start_time = timedelta(hours=start_date.hour, minutes=start_date.minute)
    lights_on_time = timedelta(hours=lights_on)
    # generate the cycles for the first day
    off_time = max(lights_on_time - start_time, timedelta(seconds = 0))
    on_time = timedelta(hours=24) - max(lights_on_time, start_time)
    cycle_start = start_date.replace(hour=0, minute=0) + timedelta(days=1)
    # add a complete cycle for each day before end_date
    while cycle_start.date() < end_date.date():
        cycle_start += timedelta(days=1)
        off_time += lights_on_time
        on_time += timedelta(hours=24-lights_on)
    # generate the partial cycles for the last day
    end_time = timedelta(hours=end_date.hour, minutes=end_date.minute)
    off_time += min(end_time, lights_on_time)
    on_time += max(end_time - lights_on_time, timedelta(seconds=0))
    return (off_time.total_seconds() / 3600, on_time.total_seconds() / 3600)
    
def get_daynight_count(start_time, end_time, lights_on, lights_off):
    if lights_on > lights_off:
        off_period = lights_on - lights_off
        on_period = 24 - off_period
        offset = timedelta(hours=-lights_off)
        off_time, on_time = cycle_times(start_time + offset, end_time + offset, lights_on - lights_off)
    else:
        on_period = lights_off - lights_on
        off_period = 24 - on_period
        offset=timedelta(hours=-lights_on)
        on_time, off_time = cycle_times(start_time + offset, end_time + offset, lights_off - lights_on)
    return (on_time / on_period, off_time / off_period)
    
date1 = datetime(year=2020, month=1, day=1, hour=9, minute=0)
date2 = datetime(year=2020, month=1, day=3, hour=13, minute=0)
date3 = datetime(year=2020, month=1, day=5, hour=20, minute=47)

print(get_daynight_count(date1, date2, 9, 17))
print(get_daynight_count(date1, date3, 9, 17))
print(get_daynight_count(date1, date2, 19, 7))
```

Output:

```
(2.5, 2.0)
(5.0, 4.236458333333333)
(2.0, 2.3333333333333335)
```

**Update**

The `cycle_times` code can be simplified by just using hour/minute math (`1 hour = 60 minutes`):

```
def cycle_times(start_date, end_date, lights_on):
    start_time = start_date.hour*60 + start_date.minute
    lights_on_time = lights_on*60
    # generate the cycles for the first day
    off_time = max(lights_on_time - start_time, 0)
    on_time = 24*60 - max(lights_on_time, start_time)
    cycle_start = start_date.replace(hour=0, minute=0) + timedelta(days=1)
    # add a complete cycle for each day before end_date
    while cycle_start.date() < end_date.date():
        cycle_start += timedelta(days=1)
        off_time += lights_on_time
        on_time += (24-lights_on)*60
    # generate the partial cycles for the last day
    end_time = end_date.hour*60 + end_date.minute
    off_time += min(end_time, lights_on_time)
    on_time += max(end_time - lights_on_time, 0)
    return (off_time / 60, on_time / 60)
```

Comment: wrapping my head around this  thanks for sharing, very cool!

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps used in the code below:

1. Define a function which determines whether a time at "day" or "night"
2. Create an array `cuts` which has starts with `start_time`, ends with `end_time`, and in between has every time where the lights change
3. Compute the amount of hours in each light and dark period
4. For each time in `cuts` (except `end_date`), check if it is at "day" or "night", and compute the time delta between it and the next time.
5. Divide each timedelta by the appropriate light or night period duration.
6. Sum and return the normalized timedeltas for the light and dark periods.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

#step 1
def is_day_or_night(time, period, lights_on=7, lights_off=19):
    lights_on = dt.time(hour=lights_on)
    lights_off = dt.time(hour=lights_off)
    val = False
    #defaults to checking if at night
    if lights_off > lights_on:
        val = time.time() >= lights_off or time.time() < lights_on
    elif lights_off < lights_on:
        val = time.time() >= lights_off and time.time() < lights_on
    #reverses if period='day'
    return val if period=='night' else not val

def get_daynight_count(start_time, end_time, lights_on, lights_off):
    #step 2
    cuts = []
    cuts.append(start_time)
    loop_time = start_time.replace(minute=0,second=0)
    while loop_time < end_time:
        loop_time += pd.Timedelta(hours=1)
        if loop_time.hour == lights_on:
            cuts.append(loop_time)
        elif loop_time.hour == lights_off:
            cuts.append(loop_time)
    cuts.append(end_time)
    days = []
    nights = []
    #step 3
    if lights_off > lights_on:
        day_hours = lights_off - lights_on
        night_hours = 24 - day_hours
    else:
        night_hours = lights_on - lights_off
        day_hours = 24 - night_hours    
    day_hours = pd.Timedelta(hours = day_hours)
    night_hours = pd.Timedelta(hours = night_hours)
    #step 4 and 5
    for i, t in enumerate(cuts[:-1]):
        if is_day_or_night(t, 'day', lights_on, lights_off):
            days.append((cuts[i+1] - t)/day_hours)
        else:
            nights.append((cuts[i+1] - t)/night_hours)
    #step 6
    return (sum(days),sum(nights))
```

For the above examples:

```
In[3]: get_daynight_count(date1, date2, 9, 17)
Out[3]: (2.5, 2.0)

In[4]: get_daynight_count(date1, date3, 9, 17)
Out[4]: (5.0, 4.236458333333333)

In[5]: get_daynight_count(date1, date2, 19, 7)
Out[5]: (2.0, 2.3333333333333335)
```